# what does this mean when automation doesn't show what i want

Tags: python, eclipse, cx-oracle

i tried to set up cx_Oracle on eclipse
but somehow even though i finished installing cx_Oracle on cmd, setting path to use sqlplus and went to Forced Builtins in python interpreter and add cx_Oracle on the list, the automation didn't show up. the only thing that is suspicious is i got two instant client folders so i set both paths in environment variable settings (i paste sqlplus file in both files). but it still didn't work.

Can someone help me? Thank you

these are what i've done so far.
as you can see the automation of cx_Oracle didn't show up.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnLFh.jpg)

sorry apparently i'm not allowed to upload multiple images since i'm new

Comment: I'd suggest using the new version called python-oracledb!

Comment: I figured this out!  The problem ocurred because I already had 2 different of python.  So cx_Oracle that i set up was applied on my older python that was supposed to be applied on the newer version.  So i deleted the older one and applied again and fixed it!